# How to read a .csv file using Renjin

Tags: java, r, grails, renjin

I have a grails application in which I want to use Renjin to carry out some statistics using R.

The code in my grails app is like this:

```
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("Renjin");
    engine.eval("data <- read.table('/path/to/my/app/R/file.csv', sep=',', na.strings=c('',' ','-','--'))");
```

When running my code I get the following Exception:

> ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - IndexOutOfBoundsException occurred when processing request:
>
> .......
>
> Index: 49, Size: 49. Stacktrace follows:
>   Message: Index: 49, Size: 49
>       Line | Method
>   ->>  635 | rangeCheck               in java.util.ArrayList

I realise that java arrays use zero based indexing, whereas R arrays use 1 based indexing, I think the issue is related to this. Is there a way to get around this issue?

Also, the CSV has 49 columns.

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace so we can see where the error is coming from?

Comment: Does it also happen when you omit the na.strings() part? It could potentially have something to do with this issue: https://github.com/bedatadriven/renjin/issues/108